# Navigationbartitle showing a white box

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, uinavigationbar

I'm working on an app and I'm having problems with navigationTitle and toolbar buttons it shows a white box above the title at my login and documents screen (see photo) on my other navigation titles I don't have that, does anyone know a solution?
Thank you in advance.

[image: Navigation bar has large space on top]

Documents screen code:

```
struct Homescreen : View {
    
    var body: some View{
        
        List{
            Text("A List Item")
            Text("A Second List Item")
            Text("A Third List Item")
                
            
            
        }
        .navigationTitle("Documents")
        .toolbar {
            Button(action: {
                
                try! Auth.auth().signOut()
                UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "status")
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("status"), object: nil)
                
            }) {
                
                Image(systemName: "person.badge.minus")
            }
}
}
}
```

Part of login screen code.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        Home()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct Home : View {
    
    @State var show = false
    @State var status = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "status") as? Bool ?? false
    
    var body: some View{
        
        NavigationView{
            
            VStack{
                
                if self.status{
                    
                    Homescreen()
                }
                else{
                    
                    ZStack{
                        
                        Login(show: self.$show)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Log in")
            .onAppear {
                
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name("status"), object: nil, queue: .main) { (_) in
                    
                    self.status = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "status") as? Bool ?? false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you might have a `NavigationView` embedded in another `NavigationView`. Keep only the first one.

Comment: And do you now what I need to do to fix it?

Comment: Remove the `NavigationView` from struct Home. You must have a `NavigationView` in early view like the TabView

Comment: It works for the log in screen but now on my documents screen there is now a navigation tile log in and document.

Comment: I fixt it and it works great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI Navigation Bar has two types of styles `.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)` and `.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)`. The white box above the title it's normal behavior of `.large` style. If your want to customize Navigation Bar more than described options you need to create your own NavBar.

That how your code looks like when I running them...
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irxOy.png)